# How to i represent date array list between two date in proper way?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have date array from between two date. But i can not represent it in pretty way of array list.

[image: My Outcome]

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-day-selection?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I want the array list as like:

```
[
 {date: "2019-12-5", day: 'Thursday'}, {date: "2019-12-6", day: 'Friday'}
]
```

Comment: why do you want to show it that way in console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and `weekday` option

```js
let startDate = new Date("2019-12-05");
let endDate = new Date("2019-12-15");

function getDateArray(start, end) {
  const arr = [];
  const dt = new Date(start);
  while (dt <= end) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt));
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  }

  const dateDayArray = [];
  for (const val of arr) {

    const year = val.getFullYear();
    const month = val.getMonth() + 1;
    const date = val.getDate();
    const fullDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + date;

    let obj = {
      date: fullDate,
      day: val.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {weekday: 'long'})
    };
    dateDayArray.push(obj);
  }
  console.log(dateDayArray);
}

getDateArray(startDate, endDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-day-selection-qq1v6g?file=src/app/app.component.ts) using `days` array. It is faster than any computations.

```
const days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

getDateArray(start, end) {
  const arr = [];
  const dt = new Date(start);
  while (dt <= end) {
      arr.push(new Date(dt));
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  }
  // console.log(arr);

const dateDayArray = [];
for (const val of arr) {

const year = val.getFullYear();
const month = val.getMonth()+1;
const date = val.getDate();
const fullDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + date;

let obj: any = {
    date: fullDate, day: days[val.getDay()]
    };
  dateDayArray.push(obj);
}
console.log(dateDayArray);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). Using momentjs, you can convert the date into any format.

`const dt = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-dd');`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var days = [ "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

this.output = this.input.map(item => ({
  date: item.date,
  day: days[item.day],
}));
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-orgdbq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**